# ELM-LANG how to make http request when clicking on browser back button

Tags: http, navigation, history, back-button, elm

I have an url like this `/user/3` where I make a http request to get the user information.

If I move to `/user/6` I will make another http request to get this user data.

My problem is when I click on the browser back button the url move back to `/user/3` but it still the *user 6* information which are display.

How do I do this ? Is it possible to get my old model back ? Or do I have to make again a http request to get *user 3*.

My `urlUpdate` looks like this:

```
urlUpdate : Result String Route -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
urlUpdate result model =
  let
    currentRoute =
      Routing.routeFromResult result

  in
      ( { model | route = currentRoute }, Cmd.none )
```

I'm a bit lost, I don't know where to do this.

If it's not clear I would like to "catch" an event when the user click on the browser back button to get the old url and then make a http request to get again this user information.

I use the `elm-navigation` package.

I have try to do this in my `urlUpdate`:

```
urlUpdate : Result String Route -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
urlUpdate result model =
  let
    currentRoute =
      Routing.routeFromResult result

    command =
      case currentRoute of
        Routing.HomeRoute ->
          getUsers
        Routing.userRoute id ->
          getUser id
        Routing.NotFoundRoute ->
          Cmd.none

  in
      ( { model | route = currentRoute }, command )
```

Which is the same thing as my init function. It doesn't work because it make an infinite loop execute the `urlUpdate`

Comment: Which routing package are you using?

Comment: I use elm navigation. I have update my question

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using `elm-lang/navigation` module.
`urlUpdate` gets called when url changes (including
 hitting browser navigation button).

So, one way to handle the url change can be to return
 Http access command instead of `Cmd.none`
in the second return value of your `urlUpdate` function.
When the `Task` resolves or fails, `Msg` (in this example, `FetchFail` or `FetchScucceed`) will be thrown, so
that you can react by `update`ing your model.

In the sample below, I updated the model so that you can show spinner
until API call resolves.

sample:

```elm
urlUpdate : Result String Route -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
urlUpdate result model =
  case result of
    Ok url ->
      let
        userId = getUserId url
      in 
        ({ model | spinner = True }, getUserInfo userId )
    Err _ -> 
        ({ model | showErr = True }, Cmd.none )

-- API call
getUserInfo : String -> Cmd Msg
getUserInfo str =
  let
    decodeUserInfo = Json.at ["args", "userid"] Json.string
    url = "https://httpbin.org/get?userid=" ++ str
  in
    Task.perform FetchFail FetchSucceed (Http.get decodeUserInfo url)
```

Comment: I try something like this (I update my question with the example), but it didn't work because it was an infinite loop, the urlUpdate was always executed

Comment: Infinite loop...  Are you returning one of the `Cmd` from `update` function?  Navigation package provides some url modification `Cmd`.

Comment: Yes I use the `getUser ID` in a command in my update. This is execute when i click on a button after entering his id in an input

Comment: If I were you, I put `Debug.log` to everywhere I issue url changing cmds, and see which execution path is causing the loop.  If it is caused by external code (Jquery plugins and such), it may be hard to catch, though.